# ActiveRecord Survey Model ActiveRecord Associations for Doctor -> Patient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to build a survey form so that a User can select a Survey template, and then a form will be rendered with questions specific to that template.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :questions, :through=> :template
  has_many :answers, :through=> :questions
end

class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :surveys
    has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_many :answers
end


class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

The questions table has a list of 30 pre-seeded questions to go with each template:

```
  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "template_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "field_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "options"
    t.boolean  "additional"
  end

acl = Template.create(name:"ACL", body_part:"knee")
acl.questions.create(content:"Diagnosis", field_type:"text_area", category: "S")
```

I can call Patient.surveys to get a list of all surveys associated with a patient. I can call Patient.surveys.first.questions to get a list of questions associated with a given survey.

But my dilemma is that I can't figure out how to get the answer associated with a specific question for a specific survey. Because as it's setup now, each question has multiple answers from many different surveys.

Ideally I would be able to call Patient.surveys.first.questions.first.answer to get the specific answer to that question **for that survey**.

But now, I need to go something like Patient.surveys.first.questions.first.answers.where(survey_id: Survey.first.id)

So my question is:

What do I need to adjust in my associations so that I can just call:

Patient.surveys.first.questions.first.answer   to get the correct answer that is associated with BOTH the question AND the Survey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first thing to note is that you are performing multiple queries for something you can actually pop into one procedural scope. I have no idea what the big picture is to your needs so I could be totally off about what is more important for you.

To answer your question specifically, you can define a method in question that grabs the right answer.

```
def answer
   survey=Survey.joins(:templates).where(:templates {id: self.template_id, question_id: self.id}).first
   Answer.where(:survey_id => survey.id).first
end
```

Then just call it like

patient.surveys.first.questions.first.answer

You can also do scoping to get your answer directly by popping this into your answer model

```
scope :for_survey_question, lambda {|survey, question| where(:survey_id => survey.id, :question_id => question.id).first }
```

and calling it anywhere as Answer.for_survey_question(survey,question) (where survey and question are both survey and question model objects loaded and passed in as parameters respectively)

Comment: Great, I'm going to start with using your first suggestion. Regarding procedural scopes.. I'm pretty new - I'll have to look into more details on that. Any tutorials or articles you'd recommend?  Thanks!

Comment: beautiful thing about rails. You can jump right to the main sources and they fill gaps up pretty nicely. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope

Comment: And the idea is that instead of querying to find Patients, then querying to find Surveys, then querying to find questions, then querying to find answers... You're combining that all into one query to save time?

Comment: Some of it has to do with neatness, conventions and such. I find sometimes developers even take a hit with performance just so the calls are tidy (never huge hits though). In this specific case you would only call survey once, question once and answer once. In the other method you are calling survey twice. this can be made even more efficient. its a neat exercise to see how to shape your design to use scopes and stuff.

Comment: Great, I'll try refactoring everything once I get it working the dirty way. I just realized that the answer method defined] doesn't work because Survey.where(:template_id => self.template_id) actually returns an array with multiple surveys (each template has multiple surveys associated with it)

Comment: And then Answer.where(:survey_id => survey.id) will actually return an array with multiple answers because each survey has many answers

Comment: Now that I consider it. You should just call Survey.answer_to_question(q). You can do a bunch of joins the way I have changed it but do you wish to go through many steps to achieve your answers or is this behavior strictly to get the answer to a question that has to do with a specific survey?

Comment: Yes, the latter that you mentioned. Okay perfect, I'll give your answer_to_question(q) scope a shot. Really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Look okay? It's just a regular old method in my Survey model:                    def answer_to_question(q)
    self.answers.where(question_id: q.id).first
  end